# zst compression not supported by apt/dpkg

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, zstd

I'm running Debian, namely:

```
# uname -A
Linux martlins2 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and for some time I see some errors telling that *some* parts of *some* packages uses *unknown* compression while doing `apt update`. In particular, the cause of the issue lays in the middle of the `dpkg`:

```
# apt update
(...)
# apt upgrade
(...)
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 124, in readdeb
    output = subprocess.check_output(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['dpkg-deb', '-f', '/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb', 'Package', 'Source', 'Version', 'Architecture', 'Status']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 323, in <module>
    main(config)
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 104, in main
    pkg = DebianFiles.Package(deb)
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 358, in __init__
    parser.readdeb(self.path)
  File "/usr/share/apt-listchanges/DebianFiles.py", line 127, in readdeb
    raise RuntimeError(_("Error processing '%(what)s': %(errmsg)s") %
RuntimeError: Error processing '/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb': Command '['dpkg-deb', '-f', '/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb', 'Package', 'Source', 'Version', 'Architecture', 'Status']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

dpkg-deb: error: archive '/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-XiLPN8/01-libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar
.zst', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-XiLPN8/01-libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
(...)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-XiLPN8/01-libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb
(...)
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To proove it, I've run the `dpkg` command (simplified) directly:

```
# dpkg -f /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb 'Package'
dpkg-deb: error: archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb' uses unknown compression for member 'control.tar.zst', giving up
```

The file really does use such compression:

```
# file /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.107+git2109030500.d201a4~oibaf~i_amd64.deb: Debian binary package (format 2.0), with control.tar.zs, data compression zst
```

I do have installed the `zstd` package:

```
# apt search zstd
(...)
libzstd1/stable,stable,now 1.4.8+dfsg-2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  fast lossless compression algorithm
(...)
zstd/stable,stable,now 1.4.8+dfsg-2.1 amd64 [installed]
  fast lossless compression algorithm -- CLI tool
```

Furthermore, I found following dpkg bugreport: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/1764220 saying the zstd support have been added in `1.18.4ubuntu1.7` version. My version of dpkg is `1.20.9`:

```
# dpkg --version
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.20.9 (amd64).
(...)
```

so that *may* not be an issue.

I've also removed the whole contents of the `/var/cache/apt/archives/*` and re-`update && upgrade`d. Didn't help.

Do you have any tips what to do with that? Is there/Are there an further packages missing? Does the Debian version doesn't have such feature? Is it an configuration issue? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Debian’s `dpkg` package [didn’t support `zstd` compression prior to version 1.21.18](https://bugs.debian.org/892664). Support [was added just in time for Debian 12](https://tracker.debian.org/news/1407587/accepted-dpkg-12118-source-into-unstable/).

I’m guessing you’ve added a Ubuntu PPA; you shouldn’t use those with Debian.

Comment: Oh, you're right! Lessons learned: Check not only the `/etc/apt/sources.list/`, but also the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` ones.

Answer (score 15):

If you are running Debian < 12 and need to install a .deb package that uses zstd, you can repack it:

```bash
# Extract files from the archive
ar x some-package.deb
# Uncompress zstd files an re-compress them using xz
zstd -d < control.tar.zst | xz > control.tar.xz
zstd -d < data.tar.zst | xz > data.tar.xz
# Re-create the Debian package in /tmp/
ar -m -c -a sdsd /tmp/some-package.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
# Clean up
rm debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz control.tar.zst data.tar.zst
```

You should now be able to install the newly generated package:

`apt-get install /tmp/some-package.deb`

Comment: I had a deb repository running on a Debian 10 server. Had this issue when adding a recent Ubuntu deb to the repo (TigerVNC). This solution worked.

Comment: Works perfectly. Ran into this on Debian 8 (Netgear ReadyNAS OS fork).

Comment: I had to use `ar rcs some_package.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz` for the repacking instead.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on @stephen-kitt's answer, this can also occur in Ubuntu when one adds a debian official repo like `bookworm` to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then accidentally upgrades `dpkg` to the Debian version.

The fix in this case is to remove the source and `sudo apt upgrade dpkg/jammy-updates` or whatever ubuntu package shows up in `apt list`.

Comment: or if you are fortunate enough to read this before your sources are jammy, you can use ubuntu 20 (focal): `sudo apt upgrade dpkg/focal-updates`